# Child model is null on post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have seen similar questions here regarding my question but I am unable to find a suitable solution for my purpose. So I started working with the MVC and had to create a simple wizard. I created the Parent View model as,

```
public class WizardSteps
{
    public int CurrentStepIndex { get; set; }

    public WizardStep1 Step1 { get; set; }

    public WizardStep2 Step2 { get; set; }

    public WizardStep3 Step3 { get; set; }

    public WizardSteps()
    {
        CurrentStepIndex = 1;
        Step1 = new WizardStep1();
        Step2 = new WizardStep2();
        Step3 = new WizardStep3();
    }
}
```

Now I have created three partial views for each of my wizard step. For every view I used the parent model,

```
@model eFormation_MVC.Models.WizardSteps
```

For each of the fields on each of the Partial Views I used controls like this inside forms,

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Step1.FirstName, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })


@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Step2.Address, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
```

This is brief code for just giving the idea what I have done so far. I have different controller methods for each of the Partial View. I pass the Parent Model WizardSteps to the controller and pass it back to next Partial View. SO for all Partial View single model is used which has child model. Now when I post the model from Second Partial View then all the values in WizardSteps.Step1 become null. I also know that this is the actual behavior but my question is how to persist the values. What can be the proper way of doing this so that the values for every Step is not lost from the Parent model.

**Edit:**
Each partial view has its own form and I am sending the parent model WizardSteps to the controller on form submit of each partial view. The problem is that when I submit Partial View for Step 2 then the values for Step 1 in the WizardSteps becomes null. I know this happens because there are no fields for Step 1 on Step 2 partial view and controller think values as null and does not persists it.

On some related question it is suggested to Serialize the models and store it on the View and send it back to controller and de-serialize it. Some has use Sessions or TempData for storing the models but I want something which is done with models. There is a question for using MVCWizard at [MVCWizard.Wizard - Using Complex Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937776/mvcwizard-wizard-using-complex-models) but the answer to that question is so vague that I am unable to grasp it. I want something similar to the MVCWizard with the use of Merge functionality but couldn't find any example of doing so. Need help with this.

Comment: Can't you just send the whole WizardSteps to the partial Views?

Comment: @rcompanhoni Thank you for responding. Yes I am currently sending the whole WizardSteps to the controller. But the problem is that when View for Step 2 is submitted then values for Step 1 becomes null in the WizardSteps. See the edit in my question.

Comment: As soon as you say "Each partial view has its own form" you're on the wrong track. Multiple forms per page is generally a bad idea. Have you considered handling the logic of multiple submits on the Client side using Javascript?

Comment: @Nick Bailey I don't have multiple forms per view rather each partial view which is a single step in the wizard have its own form and each partial view is rendered at a time so it is not having multiple forms at one time.